# Latex Multicolumn not centering

Tags: multicolumn, multicol

In the first row the column containg A is not centering in the middle of the block only at the bottom and cant figure out why.  Here is the latex stuff

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\label{table:LG_0^0}
\centering
\caption{Laguerre Gaussian $L_0^0$ Beam improvement}
\begin{tabular}{| m{0.5cm} | m{1.5cm} | m{1cm} | m{3cm} | m{3cm} | m{3cm} |}
\hline
A &
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.3\textwidth]{D7_BH.png}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.3\textwidth]{D7_IL.png}}\\
\hline
&Iterations & error value & Initial Zernike Hologram & Final Zernike Hologram & Final Laser\\
\hline
B & 8 & $1e^{-3}$ & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{D7_IH.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{D7_FH.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{D7_FL.png}\\
\hline
C & 2 & $1e^{-2}$ & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{D8_IH.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{D8_FH.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{D8_FL.png}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result
[image: screenshot1]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Sorry about that should be fine now

Comment: Please double-check that your MWE is indeed a minimal *working* example. It doesn't compile in its current form. Please also have in mind that we do not have your image files; Have a look at the images section of the answer to the linked MWE question of José.

Comment: Welcome. // Watching your screenshot I wonder if you talk about an optical effect. I.e. when you draw an imaginary line left of the numbers on the y-axis, it seems to be centered. // It may be more evident and more pleasing to look at when you add a light-gray background for your drawings, i.e. making their bounding box or frame visible.

Comment: Your posted code does not work at all `[H]` not defined , `\includegraphics` not defined. but also do not do `[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]` it will distort the image, just specify one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, I consider it an insult to the people that are trying to help you, if you give them a document that isn't working. For example because it uses unknow images and not all required packages are included.

The problem with your setup is that the first row images are typeset in a `c` cell that doesn't vertically center its contents like the `m{..}` cells do. So these images have their baseline at the bottom and the `A` is aligned with it. So you have to make sure that the baseline of these images is in their vertical center. One way to do this is to use the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option and include `valign=c` in the `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\label{table:LG_0^0}
\centering
\caption{Laguerre Gaussian $L_0^0$ Beam improvement}
\begin{tabular}{| m{0.5cm} | m{1.5cm} | m{1cm} | m{3cm} | m{3cm} | m{3cm} |}
\hline
A &
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}}\\
\hline
&Iterations & error value & Initial Zernike Hologram & Final Zernike Hologram & Final Laser\\
\hline
B & 8 & $1e^{-3}$ & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{example-image}\\
\hline
C & 2 & $1e^{-2}$ & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm]{example-image}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified [Pieter van Oostrum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671450/31283)'s answer (+1) with extra strut.

[image]

EDIT. @OP, please remove optional argument `[draft]` of `graphicx` package to get your images back. I don't have access to your files so the document had to be compiled this way.

The code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcommand\xlocstrut[1]{\rule[\dimexpr0.55ex-0.5\dimexpr#1]{0pt}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \label{table:LG_0^0}
  \centering
  \caption{Laguerre Gaussian $L_0^0$ Beam improvement}
  \begin{tabular}{| L{0.5cm} | L{1.5cm} | L{1cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} |}
    \hline
    A
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{%
      \xlocstrut{0.31\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.3\textwidth, valign=c]{D7_BH.png}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.3\textwidth, valign=c]{D7_IL.png}} \\
    \hline
    & Iterations & error value & Initial Zernike Hologram & Final Zernike Hologram & Final Laser \\
    \hline
    B & 8 & $1e^{-3}$
    & \xlocstrut{2.65cm}%
      \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm, valign=c]{D7_IH.png}
                 & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm, valign=c]{D7_FH.png}
                               & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm, valign=c]{D7_FL.png} \\
    \hline
    C & 2 & $1e^{-2}$
    & \xlocstrut{2.65cm}%
      \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm, valign=c]{D8_IH.png}
                 & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm, valign=c]{D8_FH.png}
                               & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.5cm, valign=c]{D8_FL.png}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I set the horizontal and vertical directions to be centered, which is more beautiful.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Laguerre Gaussian $L_0^0$ Beam improvement}
\label{table:LG_0^0}
\begin{tblr}
{
hlines,
vlines,
colspec    = {Q[c,m,0.5cm]Q[c,m,1.5cm]Q[c,m,1cm]Q[c,m,3cm]Q[c,m,3cm]Q[c,m,3cm]},
cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{},
cell{1}{5} = {c=2}{}
}
A & \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image} &             &                                                                  & \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image} &                                                                  \\
  & Iterations                                                                         & error value & Initial Zernike Hologram                                         & Final Zernike Hologram                                                             & Final Laser                                                      \\
B & 8                                                                                  & $1e^{-3}$   & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.5cm,valign=c]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.5cm,valign=c]{example-image}                   & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.5cm,valign=c]{example-image} \\
C & 2                                                                                  & $1e^{-2}$   & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.5cm,valign=c]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.5cm,valign=c]{example-image}                   & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.5cm,valign=c]{example-image} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]